# ISC-DHCP server disabled, but "ip address show" still show local IP assigned for eth0

Tags: 14.04, configuration, dhcp, ip, dhcpd

I installed and used ISC-DHCP server for a while for local network, then stopped it as don't need it anymore. 
`sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop`

I also changed back configuration changes of **interface** file in `/etc/network/interfaces` (i.e. settings for static IP address).

But when I run `ip address show` command, it still show fixed IP address I had previously on eth0 interface:

```
inet 192.168.16.100/24 brd 192.168.16.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have WAN ip address and internet connection is working too.
How to correct this?

Comment: whats in your /etc/network/interfaces file

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains only `auto lo
iface lo inet loopback` (default values).

Comment: eth0 still has the lease from the old dhcp server and you didn't take it down before removing the interface config. You can take it down with ifconfig down eth0

Comment: Do you meant change back settings in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`? (comment out subnet,etc)

Comment: if you aren't running the dhcp service the config will sit there doing nothing

Comment: I removed **eth0** within INTERFACES="" in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`, the isc-dhcp-server status is `stop/waiting`.